# Rails 4.0.13 composed_of set default value when nil assigned

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, aggregation

Using rails 4.0.13

Using

```
class Shipment < ActiveRecord::Base
    composed_of :weight, 
                  class_name: 'Weight',
                  mapping: [[wight_value, :value], [weight_unit, :unit]],
                  converter: :build
end
```

I need to assign some default value when
shipment.weight = nil

P.S : I don't want to allow nil value but if somehow by external input comes then I would like to assign Weight.new(0)

Note: tried with converter but it fails when nil is passed
like converter:

```
Proc.new {|value| Weight.new(value || 0)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use to_i to convert nil value into integer like:-

```
Proc.new {|value| value.blank? ? Weight.new(value.to_i) : Weight.new(value)}
```

Comment: Nope. This won't work as converter is not called when value passed is nil and allow_nil option is false